# mysql visit and payment totals by country and payment method

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to show unique patient visits and payment method totals by country specific, the number of total unique visits are correct, but the problem I am having is left join sums the records multiple times, for example when a patients visits the hospital 3 times in the specific month, the left join sums the patient payment three times, which gives the wrong total overall.

How can I make left join sum the payment only once, instead of the number of patient visits?

```
SELECT
    country.country_name
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT app.patient_id) AS total_unique_visits
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 1, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as cash_payments
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 3, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as eft_payments
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method IN (2,4), (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as card_sales
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 5, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as cheque_sales
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 6, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as bond_sales
FROM 
    appointments app 
    INNER JOIN patients p ON p.id = app.patient_id
    INNER JOIN countries country ON country.id = p.p_country
    LEFT JOIN payments pay ON pay.patient_id = app.patient_id AND (pay.payment_date >= '2022-05-01' AND pay.payment_date <= '2022-05-31') AND pay.is_deleted = 0
WHERE 
    app.company_id = 111111111 AND 
    app.clinic_id = 15 AND 
    app.patient_id > 0 AND 
    app.appointment_status = 4 AND 
    (DATE(app.start_date) >= '2022-05-01' AND DATE(app.end_date) <= '2022-05-31') AND 
    app.status = 1
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    country.country_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sum the payments first and then only join it with your query -

```
SELECT
    country.country_name
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT app.patient_id) AS total_unique_visits
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 1, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as cash_payments
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 3, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as eft_payments
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method IN (2,4), (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as card_sales
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 5, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as cheque_sales
    ,ROUND(SUM(IF(pay.payment_method = 6, (payment_amount * rate), 0)),2) as bond_sales
FROM 
    appointments app 
    INNER JOIN patients p ON p.id = app.patient_id
    INNER JOIN countries country ON country.id = p.p_country
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT patient_id, payment_method, SUM(payment_amount) payment_amount
                 FROM payments
                GROUP BY patient_id, payment_method) pay ON pay.patient_id = app.patient_id 
                                                        AND (pay.payment_date >= '2022-05-01' 
                                                             AND pay.payment_date <= '2022-05-31') 
                                                        AND pay.is_deleted = 0
WHERE 
    app.company_id = 111111111 AND 
    app.clinic_id = 15 AND 
    app.patient_id > 0 AND 
    app.appointment_status = 4 AND 
    (DATE(app.start_date) >= '2022-05-01' AND DATE(app.end_date) <= '2022-05-31') AND 
    app.status = 1
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    country.country_name
```

Since I do not have your table structure and data so this query is untested but this will give you a basic idea to proceed further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but again the payment method totals gives the duplicate sums @Ankit Bajpai

Comment: Since this question is closed. Please post another question with sample data in your tables.